# Supermicro server head won't power on

Tags: hardware, supermicro

We have a SuperMicro server that won't power up.

Specs:

- Chassis: CSE-847BE1C-R1K28LPB
- Motherboard: X10DRH-iT
- Processor: 2x Intel Xeon E5-2643v4 6 Core 3.4GHz
- Memory: 128GB DDR4 (4 x 32GB )
- Backplane: BPN-SAS3-846EL1 - Supermicro 24-Port SAS 12Gb/s 4U
- Power Supplies: 2x PWS-1K28P-SQ

The IPMI boots up just fine but the system itself does nothing.

No beeps, No fans, No indicator lights.

Some symptoms:

- On plug-in, the power light on the power supplies go amber for a second then go off.
- On plug-in, the power light will stay amber if the MB 24pin is not connected.

Here's what I've tried so far.

- Swapped Power supplies for known good.
- Swapped Motherboard
- Bare bones boot.  CPU1 in socket only. (Both w/ and w/o RAM installed)
- Swapped CPUs

I'm a bit stuck here.  It almost feels like there is a short somewhere but I've changed out the motherboard (checked for standoffs), it would be strange for there to be a random short in the system after a year+ of operations.

**EDIT (RESOLVED):**

This has been resolved.   The culprit appears to be a bad power distribution board in the chassis.  After swapping components into a different chassis, everything works.  Both MB, All CPUs, RAM, and All power supplies are good. The backplane also appears to be functional from the original case.

Comment: Usually if a poweron without RAM does not make the system beep in error, it mean CPU or motherboard, but as you switched them I hope you didnt had a dead second motherboard, happened to me one time for a HP server to receive a DOA motherboard that caused same symptom.

Comment: If it's only a year old it should still be under warranty. Use it.

Comment: Disconnect the backplane and all other peripherals.

Comment: Great that you were able to solve it, but please don't edit your solution into the question. Please add it as an answer and accept it when you are allowed to, otherwise the question stays unsolved in the system forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(RESOLVED):**

This has been resolved.   The culprit appears to be a bad power distribution board in the chassis.  After swapping components into a different chassis, everything works.  Both MB, All CPUs, RAM, and All power supplies are good. The backplane also appears to be functional from the original case.